# crop image buffer returned in jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation before calling jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I am writing a camera app. Following is my code to capture a still image:

```
[_stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:connection completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {
    NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
    UIImage *originalImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    UIImage *croppedImage  = [self cropImage:originalImage];
    [self.delegate cameraVC:self didCaptureImage:croppedImage];
}];
```

The main code in [self cropImage:] is:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(cropSize, YES, 1);    
CGRect thumbnailRect = CGRectZero;
thumbnailRect.origin = thumbnailPoint;
thumbnailRect.size.width  = scaledWidth;
thumbnailRect.size.height = scaledHeight;

[image drawInRect:thumbnailRect];
newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

However, it turns out such cropImage function is very slow. In fact, I tried several cropping methods applied on originalImage, and they are all slow.

Therefore, I am thinking if it is possible to modify the returned imageDataSampleBuffer before calling

```
[AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer]
```

such that the generated jpeg data is already the correctly cropped image.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

UIGraphics functionalities are thread safe, so you can easily perform the cropping on a different queue using GDC or on a different thread than main.
Probably is slow because the captured image is very big. 
Here some solution that you can apply:

1. Use your cropping function on a different queue, wrap the call on a `dispatch_async` by using one of the GDC low priority queues
2. Convert the image into a `CIImage` and apply a `CIFilter` that crops it. Pay attention that you need to create a `CIContext`. This is a intensive operation, but once you create one you don't need to create another. The context can be created using GPU or CPU, the choice depends on different spec, I think that GPU would be fine for your purpose. Furthermore there is a nice method that can convert a `CVPixelBufferRef` into a `CIImage`. `CVPixelBufferRef` is contained inside the `CMSampleBufferRef`.
3. In iOS8 Apple introduced new APIs to convert `CVPixelBufferRef` directly into a `vImage_Buffer`, the accelerate frameworks contains efficient methods to do really fast an thread safe operations on images<strike>, also cropping</strike>. 
   If you are thinking to obtain the image from CVPixelBufferRef pay attention about image orientations.